# Error while ngFor wrong object

Tags: json, angular, api, angular-ng-if

im getting an error while doing ngIf

```
<li *ngFor="let patient of patients">
        {{patient.id}}

    </li>
```

my component looks like this:

```
   private showAllPatients() {
   this.patientService.getAll().subscribe(patients => { this.patients = 
   patients; });
```

}

the response from the api looks like this:

```
{
"patientProfiles": [
    {
        "id": "159",
        "firstName": "Anne",
        "lastName": "Frank"

    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "firstName": "Max ",
        "lastName": "Start"  
    }]}
```

I gues the problem is becaus of the "patientProfiles" But how can i access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access like **`patients.patientProfiles`**

```
<li *ngFor="let patient of patients.patientProfiles">
```

Comment: great. Thanks al lot. I can accept the answer in 10min.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia haha ! you are funny

Comment: @FabianTschullik No need to upvote just mark as answer :P